# Replace part of field with values from query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a field that is populated with a series of criteria in a specific format:

```
CRITERIA
$1 = True
$2 > $3
```

The criteria information is stored in a table

```
CRIT_ID CRIT_DESCRIPTION
1       Example 1
2       Example 2
3       Example 3
```

The final output should look like this

```
CRITERIA
Example 1 = True
Example 2 > Example 3
```

Can anyone suggest how best to accomplish this? I have tried REPLACE and dabbled with REGEXP_REPLACE so far...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps not the most efficient, but it works recursively (that is, if the `crit_description` itself contains "placeholders", those are expanded as well. (A first solution, simpler than what's shown below, didn't do this recursive step.) See the third sample input which I added. I will post again later if I can clean it up some more.

NOTE: This assumes all "placeholders" are actually found in the `criteria_info` table; I didn't test what happens if they are not found. OP to state the requirement.

```
with
     inputs ( criteria ) as (
       select '$1 = True' from dual union all
       select '$2 > $3'   from dual union all
       select '$1 = $4'   from dual
     ),
     criteria_info ( crit_id, crit_description ) as (
       select 1, 'Example 1' from dual union all
       select 2, 'Example 2' from dual union all
       select 3, 'Example 3' from dual union all
       select 4, '$2 + $3'   from dual
     ),
     rec ( criteria, new_str ) as (
       select  criteria, criteria
         from  inputs        
       union all       
       select  r.criteria, 
               regexp_replace(r.new_str, '\$\d+', c.crit_description, 1, 1)
         from  rec r inner join criteria_info c
               on to_number(regexp_substr(r.new_str, '\$(\d+)', 1, 1, null, 1)) = c.crit_id
         where regexp_substr(r.new_str, '\$\d+') is not null
     )
select criteria, new_str
from   rec
where  regexp_substr(new_str, '\$\d+') is null
;


CRITERIA  NEW_STR
--------- ------------------------------------
$1 = True Example 1 = True
$2 > $3   Example 2 > Example 3
$1 = $4   Example 1 = Example 2 + Example 3

3 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following query I'm using the first SPACE as a separator between the id and the equation (and assuming that the id always start on the second char).

```
SELECT B.CRIT_DESCRIPTION || SUBSTR(A.CRITERIA, INSTR(A.CRITERIA, ' '))
  FROM A, B
 WHERE TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(A.CRITERIA, 2, INSTR(A.CRITERIA, ' ') - 2)) = B.CRIT_ID
```

Comment: Thanks Neria, but this does not allow for multiple criteria appearing in the field (see line 2)

Comment: It also fails at runtime with an "invalid number" exception. Did you test the code before posting it?

Comment: @mathguy Thanks, I fixed the last parameter in the WHERE's `SUBSTR`.