# How to use replace command for multiple characters in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, replace, plsql

I'm writing a procedure that have to replace a set of special characters with another set of them that are accepted to an application system. How can I re-write better the following statement that I'm using in the procedure?

```
select     replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace('%BICI* "(MOTO), |X PLAY? 4G: RED&WHITE& \/<DIRETTA>','(','-'),'%','perc'),'?','.'),'|','-'),':',';'),',','.'),'<','-'),'>','-'),'&','and'),'\','-'),'/','-'),'"','-'),')','-'),'*','-')
from dual;
```

I can't use a recursive procedure. 
Any suggestions?

Thanks!
Ilaria

Comment: You can use regexp_replace().

Comment: See my response [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28584627/319875)

Comment: Maybe this Answer can fit your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2947787/6773490

Comment: How are the mappings determined - are they in a table? Or do you need to hard-code them? (Definitely hoping it's the former and not the latter!) Then, what do you mean by "can't use a recursive procedure" - do you mean you can't use procedures? Can you use recursive queries? (That is a straight SQL concept, it has nothing to do with procedures.) Finally, after you make all the substitutions, is it possible that the new string again has possible "substitution substrings" and if so, do you need to call this again upon itself until all possible substitutions are made?

Comment: The question of "recursive queries" depends on your Oracle version, is it 11.2 or above? If it is, and especially if you need the solution to continue to substitute recursively until no further substitution is possible, you may want to take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39224899/replace-part-of-field-with-values-from-query/39226473#39226473 (Still working on cleaning it up some more!)

Comment: The mappings are in a table. I don't want to use a recursive procedure because the values are retrieved by a query. I just need to compare the string after all the replacement

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to replace multiple strings together in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83856/how-to-replace-multiple-strings-together-in-oracle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an interesting one.  Here's a working example based on Florin's example:

```
with trans_tbl(id, symbol, txt) as (
  select 1, '(', '-'    from dual union
  select 2, '%', 'perc' from dual union
  select 3, '?', '.'    from dual union
  select 4, '|', '-'    from dual union
  select 5, ':', ';'    from dual union
  select 6, ',', '.'    from dual union
  select 7, '<', '-'    from dual union    
  select 8, '>', '-'    from dual union   
  select 9, '&', 'and'  from dual union   
  select 10, '\', '-'   from dual union    
  select 11, '/', '-'   from dual union
  select 12, '"', '-'   from dual union
  select 13, ')', '-'   from dual union
  select 14, '*', '-'   from dual 
),
data_tbl(str) as (
  select '%BICI* "(MOTO), |X PLAY? 4G: RED&WHITE& \/<DIRETTA>' from dual
),
working_tbl(str, id) as (
  SELECT str, 0 id 
  FROM data_tbl 
     UNION ALL
  SELECT replace(working_tbl.str,symbol,txt), trans_tbl.id
  FROM working_tbl 
  JOIN trans_tbl 
    ON working_tbl.id = trans_tbl.id - 1
)
--select str, id from working_tbl;
SELECT str 
from working_tbl 
where id = (select max(id) 
            from trans_tbl);

STR
----------------------------------------------------------
percBICI- --MOTO-. -X PLAY. 4G; REDandWHITEand ---DIRETTA-
```